# unable to locate runnable browser (trying to click a button using webbrowser)

Tags: python

hi so i want to search in phone number and count up from 00-99 and the count works and stuff but how do i get it to do it on the website. I run the py and a new tab is open on the website but it still says error. I use Brave browser and it opens it but then says unable to locate webbrowser.Error //once i fix this how do i set it so it will then click and count where i want

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://www.advancedbackgroundchecks.com/phone')
xpath = webbrowser.get('/html/body/section[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input')

number = input('enter number: ')
count = 0
while count <= 100:
        print(str(number) + str(count).zfill(2))
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: help plese im noob python and this is my first project

Comment: _says xpath is wrong_ Are you getting an error? If so, please share the entire error message.

Comment: @AMC it says     raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Comment: it opens the browser so i am confused and how would i get it to count in that button

Comment: You wrote that the error is about the XPath, yet that doesn't look like it is?

Comment: ok ill editt the question @AMC